# How to use python-rsvg in ubuntu 18?

Tags: python, pycairo, librsvg, rsvg

In ubuntu 18 `python-rsvg` is not available as a package. I need to render an svg to a pyCairo context, basically:

```
handle = rsvg.Handle(path_to_svg_file)
handle.render_cairo(context)
```

Is there an alternative python binding for `rsvg`, or a different way I can do this without `rsvg` that would work on python 2?